# Is it possible to refer to an object from its constructor

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have an API which looks like this

```
Task<int> GetNumberFromDB(string input, IProgress<string> progress)
```

I'm trying to use the NotifyTaskCompletion pattern to use this API in a view model, so I can monitor progress, completion error etc. I'm trying to extend it to show StatusString

The constructor of the class currently looks like `NotifyTaskCompletion<T>(Task<T>)` How can I pass in a lambda such that the progress gets updated on the NotifyTaskCompletion method?

`NotifyTaskCompletion(GetNumberFromDB(input, new Progress<string>((status) => { NotifyTaskCompletion.Status = status; }))`

I know the outer object hasn't even been constructed yet so there's no real good way to refer to it. I'm open to a suggestions on a better way of handling this case.

Comment: That Level of progress reporting is usually way more trouble then it is worth. Honestly, the parsing of hte Data should not take long to begin with. If you do the bulk of filtering and paging in the query, there should not be enough data for this to be even a factor.

Comment: Yes you can do it like this: `NotifyTaskCompletion<int> x = null; x = new NotifyTaskCompletion<int>(GetNumberFromDB(input, new Progress<string>((status) => { x.Status = status; }))`